# MSBuildWorkspace.Create() throws System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException

Tags: msbuild, roslyn

I have Visual Studio 2015. I also have installed MSBuild Tools 2015. The following code gives me exception when I update Microsoft.CodeAnalysis to 2.2.0

```
var workspace=MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
```

Comment: What are the InnerExceptions?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the MSBuild libraries to your project (Microsoft.Build, Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core etc) from Nuget (for example).

I think, that a better solution is a work with the Roslyn 2.2.0 libraries in Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: I added Microsoft.Build, Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core, this error no longer occurs, but the following code project.Documents.Count () is 0.

Solution solution = workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(m_Context.CheckParam.SlnFullPath).Result;
var project=solution.Projects.First();